# PHP code for selecting random column data for every user

Tags: php, sql

PHP code:

```
$result = executeQuery("select * from question where testid=" . $_SESSION['testid'] . " order by qid;");
```

the above code select same sequence of questions for every user I want the sequence of questions to be changed every time the user start the test

Answer (score 0):

you can use random function in order by.

```
 ORDER BY RAND()

 $result = executeQuery("select * from question where testid=" . $_SESSION['testid'] . " order by RAND();");
```

Comment: var_dump $result  and see the data

Comment: after adding order by rand it gives error "failure to select questions for you"

Comment: this is you custom comment message "failure to select questions for you", what exactly mysql return after executing query ??

Comment: var_dump($result); after using this code in my php still the same result questions are coming in serial and not in random

Comment: var_dump($result); after using this code in my php still the same result questions are coming in serial and not in random but when i used code SELECT * FROM `question` where testid=1 order by rand() in phpmyadmin the question were getting arranged in random manner but when i run my php code in mozilla the questions do not come in random manner